# How to stop multiple Favicon requests in Nuxt app?

Tags: nuxt.js

The app is configured with a custom Favicon. On checking the dev tool's network tab, with filters removed, one can see multiple duplicate requests for the same resource.

This slows down the app's load speed.

[image: Multiple favicon requests]

How do we stop this?

Comment: The duplicate network happens on each client-side routing?

Comment: @BallonUra yes, it does